# How to assign value to ngModel from ngrx by also updating the ngModel once the observable is updated?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a component named posts-form and it is being populated with data from an observable ngrx.

The main problem is, although the values are being seen visually, that it is being populated.

it is not being identified / detected as values when I access pass values.
Or even just console log it. It will still have the empty values from the instance of ngModel / public variables.

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]
  [image: 3]
  [image: 4]

Comment: Please edit your question. Insert code into the question as text, not as link to screenshot

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

When you have a situation where you have an `Observable` that is passed to some other component, you should use getters and setters.

Let's say you're passing an Observable, async, to some component

```
<dumb-component [myvalue]="myObservable$|async">
```

In this dumb component you have a member variable `myvalue`.

DumbComponent:

```
class DumbComponent implements OnInit {
  private _myvalue;
  get myvalue() {
    return this._myvalue;
  }
  @Input()
  set myvalue(value) {
    this._myvalue = value;
    if (value) {
      // assume we're expecting an array that is at least 1 element long
      if (value.length > 0) {
        // do something with value[0].title or whatever
        // because here our value is populated
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in the above the Observable emits 3 values.
1. undefined
2. `[]`
3. an array of elements

This is an example for arrays.

If you have just a plain, non-array value you can skip the 2nd check (if). You can of course write your own checks to check if the value that is passed to the setter is valid.